# How can I import nbib to emacs bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

how can I import to emacs jabref the bibliographic contents exported from pubmed in nbib format?

Comment: You can use the trial version of `endnote` to convert your current file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [endnote](http://endnote.com/). The tool can convert from `pubmed` to `nbib`. (see [Knowledge database](http://endnote.com/support/search-knowledgebase)).

The tool `endnote` isn't for free, but you can use the trial version for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

apparently there is also a tool called TexMed available that should be able to do this (for free): http://www.bioinformatics.org/texmed/

and another one called: PubTex that is also on github:
https://github.com/omarwagih/pubtex
https://www.biostars.org/p/89916/